# How to run pure sql in sqlx

Tags: sql, go, sqlx

The sqlx extends the `database/sql` library and have `Exec|Query` function to run the pure sql without argument, but when i tried to run `sqlx.Exec` it said `the sqlx have no Exec function`. How to let sqlx run the pure sql method without any argument?

Comment: To be able to use `Exec`/`ExecContext` from the stdlib you need an instance of `sqlx.DB`, or `sqlx.Conn`, or `sqlx.Tx`, or `sqlx.Stmt`. The `sqlx` package itself does not implement and export an `Exec` *function*, which is why trying to invoke `sqlx.Exec` is invalid and will fail to compile.

Comment: When you're getting an error from some code, it's helpful to *include the code that causes the error* in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) is a [package](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages). Packages do not have [methods](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations), they may have [functions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations).

[Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) may have methods. The [`sqlx.DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB) type is what you're looking for. It embeds the [`*sql.DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB) type which have a [`DB.Exec()`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Exec) method, which is promoted and is available on a value of type `*sqlx.DB` too.

So first you need an `*sqlx.DB` value, by connecting to the database, something like this:

```
db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=foo dbname=bar sslmode=disable")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

Here `db` is of type `*sqlx.DB`. Then you may use the `Exec()` method:

```
result, err := db.Exec("SELECT * FROM mytable")
```